# how to append data in an existing pdf?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I'm trying to add some data to a PDF with iText 7 in a Java application.

I don't succeed in opening the pdf in append mode. I looked for some solutions online but all concerned iText5 (and use classes that doesn't exist any more.)

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want specifically:

1. **merge two documents:**
   https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-examples/itext-7-merging-pdf-documents
2. **add content at the end of a document:**
   Similar to before, you could create a new document (to a byte output stream), and merge the two together
3. **add content to an existing page:**
   Hard to do, since that typically requires re-layout of the document, which no PDF-engine can currently do.
4. **fill in forms in the document:**
   https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-examples/itext-7-form-examples
5. **add an attachment to the document:**
   https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/miscellaneous/clone-embedded-files

extra (3):

Adding content to a PDF, in the middle of existing content is extremely hard.
To understand why, here is some information on how PDF documents are built internally:

- PDF documents contain instructions for a viewer to render, rather than plain text
- instructions and their arguments are grouped in 'objects'
- objects can be compressed to reduce file size
- a PDF document keeps an internal index of all of these objects, this is called the XREF table
- the index inside a PDF document uses byte-offsets to tell a renderer where (in the file) an object can be found

Suppose you want to change (or add) something.
You'd mess up all the byte-offsets in the XREF. No viewer would be able to find any object again.
Then there is the fact that the PDF does not contain layout information. If you added something new, and existing content would need to move, you need layout information (what objects make a sentence? which sentences make a paragraph?). Only by having layout information can you sensibly re-layout the document.

Comment: it should be the number 3,is it very hard to do?

Comment: if i get the text of the last page,remove it,and add the new text to a PdfPage and append it at the bottom of my document?

Comment: @thenoobdeveloper It is something that a noob can't do because he doesn't understand PDF, and an expert won't do because he understands PDF.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie beautifully phrased

Comment: @JorisSchellekens We could put this phrase in a frame, and hang it on the wall at the office :D

Comment: So it's impossible to do

Comment: @BrunoLowagie can you suggest where can i study pdf?